# how to set up drupal Rules for a proximity alert when a user (with SmartIP) nears mapped points on openlayers?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-rules

how can Drupal rules be set up so that when a user nears a mapped node on openlayers view (with Drupal Rules + Smart IP + Proximity) they receive a sound alert (eg to their smart phone, otherwise email), and view of the mapped node?